# Make an OpenStack image public, available to all of my users

Tags: openstack, eucalyptus

I have a 2 node Openstack deployment configured.  Presently I have one image installed from the Eucalyptus website.  The image is set as 'private' I would like to make it 'public' so all users on the Openstack deployment can use it.  I can't quite figure out how to make this happen.

Here is the euca-describe-image output for the ami.

IMAGE   ami-00000006    centos53-image-bucket/centos.5-3.x86-64.img.manifest.xml        available   private     x86_64  machine aki-00000004    ari-00000005        instance-store

Comment: Actually, this solved itself by me running an apt-get upgrade on the Horizon Dashboard.  You can now edit the images availability via the dashboard.  This is great.

Answer (score 2):

openstack image set --public  IMAGE_ID

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the glance CLI to change image properties.

use

```
glance image-list
```

to get a list of images, and them something like:

```
glance image-update ########-####-####-####-############ --is-public=true
```

to change it's setting to public